# jquery an div tags used in a ordered list

Tags: jquery

i'm not sure where my errors are lying but here is my scenario...

i have an un-ordered list in html that handles my main link bar...

```
    <ul id="navlist">

 <li><a href="/" id="current">home</a></li>

 <li><a href="#" id="search">search</a></li>

 <li><a href="#" id="users">login</a></li>    

</ul>
```

and what i want done is to call each id and have jQuery handle each  and dislpay it where specified in my css file... for now, lets just ignore my "home" link...

here is a snippet of my inline jquery

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("a").click(function ()
    {
        $("div#login").slideToggle("fast");
    });
})
```

Now, whichever div i specify, it calls that ... however it will only call one div, using either  from the un-orderd list, as mentioned above in the html.

My Goal is to call a search bar when search is clicked, and to call a login box when login is clicked.

to my knowledge (noob), i believe use an  as a class, however that is what brings me here.

i believe my error is in my jquery and not my css, as stated above, either  instance will be displayed when the jquery function calls either  tag.

any help is greatly appreciated.

thanks in advance

shan2on

Answer (score 0):

Can you post more of your HTML and script?

You can attach a listener on the click event for search by the following:

```
$("#search").click(function()
{
    $("#searchBox").slideToggle();  //Assuming the id of the search box is 'searchBox'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you want to display some content when the user clicks a link of your list, and that displayed content it's diferent for each link ?

If so, you can do like this:

**HTML (no changes made here)**

```
<ul id="navlist">

 <li><a href="/" id="current">home</a></li>

 <li><a href="#" id="search">search</a></li>

 <li><a href="#" id="users">login</a></li>    

</ul>
```

**SCRIPT (changed)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").click(function () {
    var Id_to_Class = $(this).attr("id");
    $("div." + Id_to_Class).slideToggle("fast");
  });
});
```

Like this when you click the element "a", the script will collect it's id value, and call a div with that value as an class!

Ps: It's not tested, but should be ok! If this is what you want and you need that tested, let me know! ;)

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<ul id="navlist">
    <li><a href="/" id="current">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#search" class="showbox">search</a></li>
    <li><a href="#login" class="showbox">login</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="search" class="box">Content for  id "search" Goes Here</div>
<div id="login" class="box">Content for  id "login" Goes Here</div>
```

Explanation: I use the selector for the search bar and login box in the respective `href` attribute. Those `<a>`s that are involved has a classname so I that I can just select them w/o selecting other `<a>`s. I also gave the boxes a common classnames so i can reference to all of them.

jQUery:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('a.showbox').click(function() {
        var theBoxToShow = $(this).attr('href'); // Line 1
        $('.box').slideUp().filter(theBoxToShow).slideDown(); // Line 2
        return false; // Line 3
    });
});
```

Explanation: Only `a.showbox` will be involved in the onclick here. Line 1 gets the selector of the element i want to show (search bar/login box). Line 2 hides all the boxes, filter only the box that relates to the clicked `<a>`. Line 3 to prevent browser from jumping to top.

You can `display:none` the `div.box` in your css to hide them at first. Hope that helps.

Comment: are there any contents to the class=box inside the div tag or is this just to ease the reference ?

also is there something i should know about creating classes as opposed to simple divs in regards to jQuery ?
i'm trying your solution now, will report back ...

~ shan2on

Comment: brilliance thank you kindly...

ps - i already had the display:none in the <div> tags, as these two boxes are residing inside the same "real estate" on homepage.

again, thank you

~ shan2on

Comment: ok ... 

display:none seems to be working fine, however the animation attribute is not animating the way i like.

First click (either link), the appropriate <div> tag shows... on second click it slides up and down again.

my goal is a binary on/off type interface, switching the animation to slideToggle, does not fix this (same problem persists).

when i switch line 2 to .toggle, it calls the wrong <div> tag w/o animation. when i click search, it calls #login, i click login #search is called.

i do get the on/off feature i wanted in the .toggle effect, just w/o the effect,if that makes sense.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. If I understand you correctly, on the 2nd click of the same link the already-showing <div> slides up and down again?

If that's the case, you can add a boolean check before calling line2. 

if (theBoxToShow.is(':hidden'))

In this way, we only animate it when the box we need to show is hidden. Hope that helps.